# Rails 6 subclasses don't automatically create their own type

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6, single-table-inheritance

Following a tuto (https://devblast.com/b/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/), I created a Class and subclasses:

```
class Animal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tribe
  self.inheritance_column :race

  scope :lions, -> { where(race: 'Lion') }
  scope :meerkats, -> { where(race: 'Meerkat') }
  scope :wildboars, -> { where(race: 'Wildboar') }

  def self.races
    %w(Lion Wildboar Meerkat)
  end
end
```

and subclasses :

```
lion.rb
class Lion < Animal;end
meerkat.rb
class Meerkat < Animal; end
wildboar.rb
class Wildboar < Animal;end
```

and also a relateed class to animals :

```
class Tribe < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :animals
  # delegate :lions, :meerkats, :wild_boars, to: :animals
  delegate :lions, :meerkats, :wildboars, to: :animals

end
```

Seems that races where implemented as in the tuto, but when I create an instance of Lion, the instance race is nil :

```
Lion.new
=> #<Lion id: nil, name: nil, age: nil, race: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, tribe_id: nil>
```

The same when creating in an existing Tribe :

```
tribe.animals << Lion.new(name:'toto',age:25)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Lion Create (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "animals" ("name", "age", "created_at", "updated_at", "tribe_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "toto"], ["age", 25], ["created_at", "2020-06-28 02:03:56.598482"], ["updated_at", "2020-06-28 02:03:56.598482"], ["tribe_id", 1]]
   (6.9ms)  COMMIT
  Animal Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "animals".* FROM "animals" WHERE "animals"."tribe_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["tribe_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Animal id: 7, name: nil, age: nil, race: nil, created_at: "2020-06-27 23:59:30", updated_at: "2020-06-27 23:59:30", tribe_id: 1>, #<Animal id: 9, name: nil, age: nil, race: nil, created_at: "2020-06-28 00:16:43", updated_at: "2020-06-28 00:16:43", tribe_id: 1>, #<Animal id: 10, name: "toto", age: 25, race: nil, created_at: "2020-06-28 02:03:56", updated_at: "2020-06-28 02:03:56", tribe_id: 1>]>
```

What's missing to do so ?

Comment: Has `self.inheritance_column :race`a typo? It should be `self.inheritance_column = :race` (without the = it should be throwing an error).

Comment: Thank u again Sebastian Palma ! I spent time on such a ridiculous syntax error lol . I then notice that Lion.new is sufficient to create instance in the DB. No need to .save or .create

Comment: Was that? Nice one, even if it was a small mistake I think is worth adding your answer. STIs are from the things Rails documenation isn't strong enough.

Comment: I think in that case you must pay attention. In order to create a new record in your database you must do something to persist the object data in the database. `new` by itself doesn't do so, it only instantiates a new object from the given class, but when you use `<<`, you don't need to call save since that's done under the hood. Check out the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-3C-3C) for a bit more of info.

Comment: Good to know, great indications !

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned as a comm by Sebastian Palma, the fix for this was a syntax error :

```
self.inheritance_column = :race
```

the `=` was missing